# Azure Media Services V3 - How to get ParentAssets (available in IAsset from V2)

Tags: azure-media-services

How to get ParentAssets in Azure Media Services V3?

ParentAssets are available in legacy V2 APIs both .NET & REST apis.

**Reference**

- https://urstream.restv2.westus.media.azure.net/api/Assets('asset id')/**ParentAssets**".
- **IAsset.ParentAssets** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mediaservices.client.iasset?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not supported in the Azure media service v3 currently,
we could find all of the supported Rest APIs from the [rest-api-specs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/mediaservices/resource-manager/Microsoft.Media/stable/2018-07-01). But now there is no **ParentAssets** related information in the [rest-api-specs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/mediaservices/resource-manager/Microsoft.Media/stable/2018-07-01).

For more information about Azure Media Services v3 release notes, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/release-notes#rest-v3-ga-release).

Currently, not all of v2 features are migrated to v3, if you still want to get ParentAssets, I recommend that you could still use the v2 to instead of v3 currently.

Comment: Thanks, is the rest-api-specs link a swagger file?  How do I read it in a human form viewer?

Can I use the V2 Rest API to get V3 Parents?

Comment: How are you actually using Parents in the V2 API today? Can you explain the scenario?  We actually have not moved that over to V3 as we saw little to no usage of the feature - and it made the API a bit too much like a CMS layer.

Comment: 2 uses. 1. map caption asset, produced via indexer job, to original source asset.  2. Map mp4 asset, produced by encoder job, to original live asset.  I have worked around out by storing parent in the alternativeid.  Can the size limit for alternativeid be increased to 4K? I am using it for easy metadata.